# How to protect my application data in Documents directory

Tags: ios, security, encryption

How can I protect files in my application "Documents" directory? Using iFunBox, or another application like it, anyone can to see, what application store in it's documents directory. So if I want to store some private data, or information about in-apps status, gold, achievments or something else just in .plist-files it will be not safelly.
Maybe there is a best-practices for iOS application how to secure and protect their data?

Comment: what are you worried about? People just being able to see the information and edit it? You can hash and salt any special values so it will not be human readable.You can also write binary files or serialize your objects.

Comment: What specific threats are you seeking to secure against?  Is the data mutable or immutable?

Comment: @madmik3 I'm get some googling around this, and understand, that easiest way is to convert all values, that I write in .plist in NSData and hash it, so human can't read and change it, as you say. Now I'm want to find some library to encrypt NSData, but it's not big problem, I can write enrcypt/decrypt methods by my own, at all. So, can you make your comment an answer, in order I mark it as an accepted?

Comment: If the user uses a passcode you can make use of the standard file system protection APIs. Enable this in your provisioning profile.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to truly secure data from the user. It is naturally secured from other applications, but the user is always able to get access to everything on-disk or in memory.

That said, if you have data that the user is not supposed to access, then you should not store it in `Documents`, since this is backed up via iTunes. You should store it in `Library`. See "The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files" in the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for details on each possible location and how it is treated by the system.

Answer (score 2):

Applications you make for iOS are sandboxed, i.e., the apps feel like they are the only thing on the system. As a result, they cannot access any place outside the app. You are restricted to using the Documents, Library folders which are visible to applications like iFunBox.

Your best bet is to hash out the data and then store them to files, so that if anyone tries to edit your files it results in a hash mismatch, that you can read in your application, and make your data secure.